# Write CSV from List of HashMaps with Header using Apache Commons CSV

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-csv

I have to take an `ArrayList` of `HashMap` and create a CSV using Apache Commons CSV. However, it's not writing the values to the right headers. Is there an easy way to have the library automatically place the values to the right headers using the Enum? I don't want to manually assign it as I will be adding more columns.

This is what it's producing:

[image]

Here is what I have:

Header.java

```
public enum Header
{
    FIRST_NAME(),
    LAST_NAME(),
    GENDER();
}
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Map<Header, String>> output = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<Header, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(Header.FIRST_NAME, "John");
    map.put(Header.LAST_NAME, "Andrew");
    map.put(Header.GENDER, "Male");
    output.add(map);

    Map<Header, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put(Header.FIRST_NAME, "Sally");
    map2.put(Header.LAST_NAME, "Andrew");
    map2.put(Header.GENDER, "Female");
    output.add(map2);

    String outputFile = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"test.csv";

    try (
            BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputFile));
            CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                    .withHeader(Header.class));)
    {
        csvPrinter.printRecords(output);
        csvPrinter.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(TestCSV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: you man want to use jackson csv or open csv to read csv as java pojo, so you don't have to declare more enums

Comment: Not sure what you mean, as I want to specifically define the headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputFile));
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(Header.class));) {
    for (Map<Header, String> row : output) {
        csvPrinter.printRecord(Arrays.asList(Header.values())
                                     .stream()
                                     .map(header -> row.get(header))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TestCSV.class.getName())
          .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks even better than mine, as the order is taken from the Enum.

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out.  I changed the maps to `LinkedHashMap` to retain order then did this:

```
   try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputFile));
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
        .withHeader(Header.class));)
   {

        for (Map<Header, String> val : output)
        {
            csvPrinter.printRecord(val.values().toArray());
        }

        csvPrinter.flush();

    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(TestCSV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```